# The width a element in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Well, i need the size a element in swift. Bat this...

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
print(grid.frame.size.width, screenSize.width)
// 560.0 414.0
```

In the storyboard

```
View
  + Grid
  + Constrains
       + Grid.leading = leadingMargin
       + Grid.bottom = Bottom Layout Guide.top
       + Grid.top = top
       + Grid.trailing = leadingMargin
```

How do you capture the width (real) the element for Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague but here is what I see:

1. Your constraints don't seem right in any case. Why does `grid` have `trailing` to `leadingMargin`? Shouldn't it be `trailing` to `trailingMargin`?
2. When using autolayout, frames do not automatically have their correct size, try adding this code before accessing a frame dimensions:

   ```
   grid.setNeedsLayout()
   grid.layoutIfNeeded()
   ```

   This way, an autolayout pass is forced, allowing the frames to be set.